# How do I extract only the first number from a integer in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, measure

My interest is using the DAX language to extract the first number from integer. For instance the following column

| integers |
| --- |
| 33334344 |
| 23256566 |
| 34567666 |

I want the following output but I don't know how to do it because I'm new in Power Bi.
|integers|
|:------:|
|3       |
|2       |
|3       |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

```
Measure = LEFT( CONVERT(SUM(Table1[integers]), STRING),1)
```

Comment: Why is "SUM" needed?

Comment: Because it is a measure without row context.